# How to implement promise in firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have written JavaScript which retrieves data from firebase realtime database & it's working fine. I have also given a html form on each of the snapshot. But when I try to submit the form it shows an error:*Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null*. It may be because, to retrieve the data from firebase it takes some time but in the mean the time the javascript below it runs and therefore it couldn't find the submit button. I also want to attach some values to the form from the snapshot.

```js
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  //my config
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("Listings/" + "/electrician");

ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
  
  });
  var database = firebase.database();
  database.ref("Listings/" + "/electrician").once("value", function (snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      var content = "";
      content += '<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">'; //Works one time not for each
      snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
        var val = data.val();
        content +=
          "<div class=" +
          "column" +
          " " +
          "data-string=" +
          val.ServiceArea +
          "," +
          val.onlinePayment +
          "," +
          val.DoorstepService +
          "," +
          val.address +
          "," +
          val.business +
          "," +
          ">";
        content += '<div class="card">';
        content += '<div class="card-body">';
        content +=
          '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/200/000000/user-male-circle.png" height="64px" height="64px" align="left" class="algn"/>';
        content += '<p class="card-text">';
        content +=
          "<b>" +
          "<font size=" +
          "4.5" +
          ">" +
          val.business +
          "</font>" +
          "</b>" +
          "<br>";
        content +=
          '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/500/000000/marker.png" height="20px" width="20px"/>';
        content += val.address + "<br><br></br>";
        content +=
          '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/200/000000/star.png" height="20px" width="20px"/>100% positive response<br>';
        content +=
          "<img src=" +
          val.verification +
          " " +
          "height=" +
          "20px" +
          " " +
          "width=" +
          "20px" +
          " " +
          "/>" +
          "ID Verified";
        content += "<hr>";
        content += '<div class="description">';
        content += "<b>Business Hours:</b>&nbsp;" + val.BusinessHours + "<br>";
        content += "<b>Service Radius:</b>&nbsp;" + val.ServiceArea + "<br>";
        content += "<b>Payment Mode:</b>&nbsp;" + val.onlinePayment + "<br>";
        content +=
          "<b>Doorstep service:</b>&nbsp;" + val.DoorstepService + "<br>";
        content += "<b>Services:</b>&nbsp;" + val.services + "<br>";
        content += "</div>";
        content += "</p>";
        content += '<ul style="display: inline-block";>';
        content +=
          "<a href=tel:" +
          val.phone +
          ">" +
          "<li><button class='btn btn-primary'>Call now</button></li></a>";
        content +=
          "<a href=https://wa.me/91" +
          val.phone +
          ">" +
          "<li><button class='btn btn-success'>WhatsApp</button></li></a>";
        content += "</ul>";
        /*   content +=   */
        content += '<div class="alert" id="greeting"></div>';
        content += '<form id="contactForm">';
        content +=
          '<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required/>';
        content +=
          '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required />';
        content +=
          '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />';
        content +=
          '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Enter todays date" />';
        content +=
          '<textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>';
        content +=
          '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="line-height: initial;">Submit</button>';
        content += "</form>";
        content += "</div>";
        content += "</div>";
        content += "</div>";
      });
      $("#ex-table").append(content);
    }
  });
});
// reference testme collection
var testmeRef = firebase.database().ref("testme");

/* Event Listener */

document.getElementById("contactForm").addEventListener("submit", submitForm);

// Submit form
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var name = getInputVal("name");
  var email = getInputVal("email");
  var subject = getInputVal("subject");
  var date = getInputVal("date");
  var message = getInputVal("message");

  // save testme
  savetestme(name, email, subject, date, message);

  // show alert
  document.querySelector(".alert").style.display = "block";
  var testme = document.querySelector("#greeting");
  window.location.href = "SuccessfulMessage.html";

  // Hide alert after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector(".alert").style.display = "none";
  }, 3000);
  // Clear form after submission
  document.getElementById("contactForm").reset();
}

/* Function to get form values */
function getInputVal(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

// Save testme to firebase

function savetestme(name, email, subject, date, message) {
  var newtestmeRef = testmeRef.push();
  newtestmeRef.set({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    subject: subject,
    date: date,
    message: message,
  });
}
```

```html
 <div id="ex-table"></div>
```

Therefore I'm trying to provide Promise function, but I'm unable to do it. Or if there is any other method please mention.

[Retrieved data & the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVOBV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  //my config
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("Listings/" + "/electrician");

var myPromise = new Promise(function (myResolve, myReject) {
  ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {});
    ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        var content = "";
        content += '<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">'; //Works one time not for each
        snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
          var val = data.val();
          content +=
            "<div class=" +
            "column" +
            " " +
            "data-string=" +
            val.ServiceArea +
            "," +
            val.onlinePayment +
            "," +
            val.DoorstepService +
            "," +
            val.address +
            "," +
            val.business +
            "," +
            ">";
          content += '<div class="card">';
          content += '<div class="card-body">';
          content +=
            '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/200/000000/user-male-circle.png" height="64px" height="64px" align="left" class="algn"/>';
          content += '<p class="card-text">';
          content +=
            "<b>" +
            "<font size=" +
            "4.5" +
            ">" +
            val.business +
            "</font>" +
            "</b>" +
            "<br>";
          content +=
            '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/500/000000/marker.png" height="20px" width="20px"/>';
          content += val.address + "<br><br></br>";
          content +=
            '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/200/000000/star.png" height="20px" width="20px"/>100% positive response<br>';
          content +=
            "<img src=" +
            val.verification +
            " " +
            "height=" +
            "20px" +
            " " +
            "width=" +
            "20px" +
            " " +
            "/>" +
            "ID Verified";
          content += "<hr>";
          content += '<div class="description">';
          content +=
            "<b>Business Hours:</b>&nbsp;" + val.BusinessHours + "<br>";
          content += "<b>Service Radius:</b>&nbsp;" + val.ServiceArea + "<br>";
          content += "<b>Payment Mode:</b>&nbsp;" + val.onlinePayment + "<br>";
          content +=
            "<b>Doorstep service:</b>&nbsp;" + val.DoorstepService + "<br>";
          content += "<b>Services:</b>&nbsp;" + val.services + "<br>";
          content += "</div>";
          content += "</p>";
          content += '<ul style="display: inline-block";>';
          content +=
            "<a href=tel:" +
            val.phone +
            ">" +
            "<li><button class='btn btn-primary'>Call now</button></li></a>";
          content +=
            "<a href=https://wa.me/91" +
            val.phone +
            ">" +
            "<li><button class='btn btn-success'>WhatsApp</button></li></a>";
          content += "</ul>";
          /*   content +=   */
          content += '<div class="alert" id="greeting"></div>';
          content += '<form id="contactForm">';
          content +=
            '<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required/>';
          content +=
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required />';
          content +=
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />';
          content +=
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Enter todays date" />';
          content +=
            '<textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>';
          content +=
            '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="line-height: initial;">Submit</button>';
          content += "</form>";
          content += "</div>";
          content += "</div>";
          content += "</div>";
        });
        $("#ex-table").append(content);
        myResolve();
      }
    });
  });
});

myPromise.then(function () {
  // reference testme collection
  var testmeRef = firebase.database().ref("testme");

  /* Event Listener */

  document.getElementById("contactForm").addEventListener("submit", submitForm);

  // Submit form
  function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = getInputVal("name");
    var email = getInputVal("email");
    var subject = getInputVal("subject");
    var date = getInputVal("date");
    var message = getInputVal("message");

    // save testme
    savetestme(name, email, subject, date, message);

    // show alert
    document.querySelector(".alert").style.display = "block";
    var testme = document.querySelector("#greeting");
    window.location.href = "SuccessfulMessage.html";

    // Hide alert after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.querySelector(".alert").style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
    // Clear form after submission
    document.getElementById("contactForm").reset();
  }

  /* Function to get form values */
  function getInputVal(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
  }

  // Save testme to firebase

  function savetestme(name, email, subject, date, message) {
    var newtestmeRef = testmeRef.push();
    newtestmeRef.set({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      subject: subject,
      date: date,
      message: message,
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.